# What is the difference between code examples?

Tags: java

I have my code for "Find the missing integer" in Codility

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) if(A[i] >= 0) a.add(A[i]);
    if(a.isEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    }
    a.sort(null);
    if(a.get(0) > 1) {
        return 1;       
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.size()-1; i++) {
        if(a.get(i) != a.get(i+1) && a.get(i)+1 != a.get(i+1)) {
            return a.get(i)+1;
        }
    }
    return a.get(a.size()-1)+1;
}
```

This code works for all except Performance tests - large_1.

It gives me an error "got 233 expected 40000".

When i replace this code:

```
if(a.get(i) != a.get(i+1) && a.get(i)+1 != a.get(i+1)) 
return a.get(i) +1;
```

with

```
int a1 = a.get(i);
int a2 = a.get(i+1);
if(a1 != a2 && a1 +1 != a2) return a.get(i) +1;
```

or

```
int sub = a.get(i+1) - a.get(i);
if(sub != 0 && sub != 1) return a.get(i) +1;
```

then there are no errors.(I got 100/100 score when i replace that line)

Is there anyone who can give some explanation for the difference?

They seem the same to me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm betting it has to do with the fact that `a.get(i) != a.get(i+1)` is doing a reference check on `Integer` objects while `a1 != a2` is doing a value check on `int` primitives.

Comment: In addition to @BenP. 's comment, `!=` and `==` only work for `Integer`s in the range of -128 to 127 due to the class' caching of those values.

Comment: Note also that these sorts of questions often have "trick" solutions. In this case, if you have a list of numbers from 1 to N but are missing a single number, then you can compare the sum of all the numbers you do have to the value `(n * (n+1))/2` and the difference is the missing number.

Comment: So, if you follow the rule **not** to compare objects with `==` and use `equals()` method instead, you will be safe.

Comment: Thank u guys. These comments r very helpful for nubs in java like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(a.get(i) != a.get(i+1) && a.get(i)+1 != a.get(i+1))
```

Because `a` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, `a.get(i)` is an `Integer`, so you're comparing `Integer`s by identity here.

When you added the array elements to the list using `a.add(A[i])`, they were auto-boxed: the compiler rewrote this to `a.add(Integer.valueOf(A[i]))`.

Only `Integer`s in the range -128..127 are guaranteed to be cached by `Integer.valueOf`; so if the `Integer`'s value is outside this range, you will be comparing `Integer`s that have equal value but different identities.

On the other hand:

```
int a1 = a.get(i);    // Unboxing: int a1 = a.get(i).intValue()
int a2 = a.get(i+1);  // Unboxing: int a2 = a.get(i+1).intValue()
if(a1 != a2 && a1 +1 != a2)
```

`a1` and `a2` are primitives - you unbox them by assigning them to `int` variables - so it's fine to compare them by `==` or `!=`.

In your first version, replace `A != B`  with `!A.equals(B)` (or `!Objects.equals(A, B)`).

Comment: Thanks to you, my curiosity has been solved clearly.

Comment: *"guaranteed to be cached"* – this is guaranteed by the [Java Language Specification § 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition comparing the Integer objects which obliviously compare the address location of the objects instead of the values. And this is i am sure not expected by you.

Change your if condition to below -

if(a.get(i).intValue() != a.get(i+1).intValue() && a.get(i).intValue()+1 != a.get(i+1).intValue())